# How can I overcome a slow loading application with several app pools in IIS 7?

Tags: iis-7, recycle, application-pool

How can I overcome a slow loading application with several app pools in IIS 7 ?
And not have requests wait for the server to load (in case of recycling) and create a queue. But have the server loaded while hitting recycle condition before the first requests arrives.
Thanks,
Oshrat.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the slow load isn't a result of waiting for the original pool to complete?  This can happen if the app pool has the "Disable Overlapped Recycle" setting turned on.

Applications will load their initial state when the get the first request.  Hence you could consider having a little tool whose job it is to ping the application to get it to start before a real user attempts to use it.

Comment: The "Disable Oevrlapped Recycle" setting is turned off. 
Also, when looking on the memroy amount of the w3wp process in the task manager, that represents my process, I can see that the recycling is happening and the pool finished loading, then I trigger a new request, and only at this point the memory comes to the amount of my loaded application. What causes a late response. The second request receives a much faster response.

That's exactlly what I'm looking for  - somthing that 
will start my application before the first real request. 
Do you know of a way to do that?

Comment: @Oshrat: The tricking thing is determining when you need to ping the application to get it loaded.  One option is to have a VBScript task in scheduled tasks pinging the the application regularly using XmlHttp or WinHttp component.

Comment: Isn't there a way to ride on the Application Pool Recycling event or so?

Comment: Not that I know of but that isn't to say there isn't something you can hook.